# How to Append Filter Data on Array from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image][image][image][image]Please find my code below. How can we append filter data on array from Firebase?

```
 var childrenList = [DatabaseList]()
 let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Messages")
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for childSnapshot in snapshot.children{
                print(childSnapshot)
                self.childrenList.append(snapshot)
            }
        })
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: based on which condition, you want to filter your array?

Comment: in the database there is 10 values of VideoID. 5 are started with "12345" and the rest are "67890". i just want the filter data to append an array to show that on table view

Comment: Then use array.filter function to filter your based on the condition. Like this childrenList.filter({$0.videoID.hasPrefix("12345") })

Comment: thanks, but i already get the filter data by using
 let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for childSnapshot in snapshot.children{
                print(childSnapshot)
            }

Comment: then why you want to apply filter again, if you are fetching filtered data from firebase itself?

Comment: i just want to append the childsnapshot in my arraylist.|
for childSnapshot in snapshot.children{
                print(childSnapshot)
                self.childrenList.append(snapshot)
            }

Comment: snapshot.children is array of anyobject that is array of dictionaries, so using that dictionary you need to init your DatabaseList class and then append.

Comment: Like this?
class DatabaseList : NSObject {
    
    var MessageBody : String?
    var Name : String?
    var VideoID : String?
    
    init(MessageBody: String?, Name: String?, VideoID: String?){
        self.MessageBody = MessageBody
        self.Name = Name
        self.VideoID = VideoID
    }
}

Comment: Edited my answer below, Hope that helps.

Comment: Doing it accordingly madam.

Comment: @Rohi : Thanks a lot madam, it is working fine now

Comment: @ Gorib Developer, please accept my answer and upvote it if it helped you.

Comment: @Rohi : Doing it madam, it helped me a lot

Comment: @ Gorib Developer, please accept my answer and upvote it if it helped you with name Rohi

Comment: Already done it Madam

Comment: But not my answer @ Gorib Developer

Comment: now check madam

Comment: @ Gorib Developer. Thanks.

Comment: @Rohi : madam, can it be possible to bind the data without using reload tableView in swift. like in android 'FirebaseListAdapter' is responsible for binding as well as reloading.

Comment: @ Gorib Developer, Not sure about this. but to bind data tableView reload is required if not you can go with Rxswift.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rohi madam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Messages")
   let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
     print(snapshot)

    for (childSnapshotId, childSnapshotValue) in snapshot {
       if let dataListDict = childSnapshotValue as? [String: AnyObject] {
          //Init you newModel with the dataListDict here
          let newModel = DatabaseList(dict: dataListDict)
         print(childSnapshot)
         self.childrenList.append(newModel)
       }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})


   class DatabaseList : NSObject { 
    var messageBody : String? 
    var name : String? 
    var videoID : String? 
   init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) { 
       messageBody = dict["MessageBody"]
       name = dict["Name"]
       videoID = dict["videoID"]
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct but there are few mistakes in finishing block.

`self.childrenList.append(snapshot)` snapshot is an instance of `DataSnapshot` not a `DatabaseList` so you can not append it like this.

```
for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {

     /// childSnapshot is an instance of DataSnapshot not a dictionary but its value will be
     guard let data = (childSnapshot as! DataSnapshot).value else {continue}
     let dataDict = data as! Dictionary<String, Any>

     /// Initializing the new object of DatabaseList and passing the values from data
     let list: DatabaseList = DatabaseList()
     list.messageBody = dataDict["MessageBody"] as? String
     list.name = dataDict["Name"] as? String
     list.videoID = dataDict["VideoID"] as? String

     /// This is correct, and now you can append it to your array.
     childrenList.append(list)
 }
```

Apart from this you will have to reload the `tableView` inside the finishing block not below the block because this is an asynchronous request and data will come later.

Also its always better to check the data existence. `snapshot.exists()`.

One more suggestion if you want to fetch the data just once then do not use `.observe` use `.observeSingleEvent` instead. `.observe` will fire the block every time there is any change at this node.

**Here is the full code snippet.**

```
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

      if !snapshot.exists() {
         // Data doesn't exist
         return
      }

      for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
           guard let data = (childSnapshot as! DataSnapshot).value else {continue}
           let dataDict = data as! Dictionary<String, Any>

           let list: DatabaseList = DatabaseList()
           list.messageBody = dataDict["MessageBody"] as? String
           list.name = dataDict["Name"] as? String
           list.videoID = dataDict["VideoID"] as? String
           childrenList.append(list)
       }

       /// Reload your tableView here
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
 })
```

**And expecting the class model like below:**

```
class DatabaseList: NSObject {
    var messageBody: String?
    var name: String?
    var videoID: String?
}
```